# How to set fix time variables in php?

Tags: php

I want to set a fix time variables in php for my if and else condition.
For example:

```
$startTime = '08:00:00';
$endTime = '16:00:00';

$totalhrs = $endTime - $startTime;

echo $totalhrs;
```

Anyone know how to declare the time in PHP?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
$startTime  =   strtotime('08:00:00');
$endTime    =   strtotime('16:00:00');

$totalhrs   =   ($endTime - $startTime) / 3600;
echo $totalhrs;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

you can use datetime object for this case

```
$startTime  = new DateTime('08:00:00');
$endTime = new DateTime('16:00:00');
$totalhrs = $startTime->diff($endTime)->h;
```

Comment: I tried your syntax sir but it displayed empty when I run it.

Comment: If you use it in namespace you need change DateTime to \DateTime. if it's still not working, pls send me the error msg

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below function to check timestamps. If you don't pass it a second parameter, it will evaluate if the first time has passed the CURRENT time, otherwise it will compare the first time against the second.

```
Function timeHasPassed($Time, $Time2 = 0) {
        If ($Time2 != 0) {
         $Now = new DateTime($Time2);
        } Else {
          $Now = new DateTime();
        }
        $Then = new DateTime($Time);
        If ($Now > $Then) {
            Return TRUE;
        } Else {
            Return FALSE;
            /*
                You can also use the below code to print out how long is left until the timestamp has passed. Keep in mind, this will return TRUE if tested as a boolean so maybe consider returning a different datatype instead of TRUE if you decide to go this route.
                $Time = new DateTime($Time);
                $Now = new DateTime();
                $Remainder = $Time->diff($Now);
                $Remainder = $Remainder->format("%h hours, %i minutes, and %s seconds!");
                return $Remainder;
            */
        }
    }
```